# When to re-post a question

Tags: discussion

I originally wrote a question about a bug I found asking for help.

I eventually found out more about why the bug was happening and I feel that this new information totally changes what the question was originally asking.  However it still relates to the same bug.

Should I make a new question and delete my original one or should I update my original question?

Comment: Does the question have answers?

Comment: @psubsee2003 no it doesn't because the new found info is a big part of the bug.

Comment: Be careful. [**Avoid chameleon behaviour**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169052/245167), if anyone posts an answer before you edit, don't invalidate the current answers. It is frowned upon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends.

If, as you say, the new information "totally changes what the question was originally asking," it ***may*** merit a new post, but be careful: if the information doesn't **entirely** change the meaning of your post, you risk having it marked as a duplicate of your original question.

If your original question was unanswered, it would be best to edit it with the new information since you don't risk invalidating answers. If it has answers (upvoted or otherwise), you may want to consider posting a new question.

In situations like this, you need to ask yourself one thing:

## Does your new information *fundamentally* change the meaning of the post?

This is important: if the new information actually changes *what the question is asking*, write a new post. If it is different enough to change the post's meaning, it won't matter that it stems from the same bug.

If it doesn't change what the post is asking, it should be an edit, particularly if it doesn't have any answers. Editing it will bump it back to the top of the questions list, which has the same effect as posting a new question, so you don't lose anything in terms of visibility by editing.