# Should I edit my question, or create a new one?

Tags: support, specific-question

I'm wondering whether or not I should edit my existing question, or create a new one

[Lock-free stack - Is this a correct usage of c++11 relaxed atomics? Can it be proven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831200/lock-free-stack-is-this-a-correct-usage-of-c11-relaxed-atomics-can-it-be-pr)

I'll be posting a major code update, as well as updating the logic inside.

My concern about posting an edit instead of a new question is that it might make much of the existing comments and answers obsolete. Is that ok?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265491/when-to-re-post-a-question

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind if I run into the vote to closers again.

Answer (score 5):

> It might make much of the existing comments and answers obsolete. Is that ok?

**No.**

Ask a new question. If you want, you can refer to your previous question in your new question.

Comment: I'm also worried that it'll get flagged and closed for being a duplicate. Ty.

Comment: @MGaz: Then point the flaggers/ closers here. Meta will sort them out ;).

Comment: Ok, sounds good :D So if I have a question closed for being a dupe (when it's not), I can post here to get it looked at? (had one of those the other day...)

Comment: @MGaz: It's not a duplicate if it is a different problem. If you post the same thing again, then its a duplicate. Refer to your question in your post though

Comment: @MGaz: You have two options; either post a question on meta (and use the [meta-tag:specific-question] and [meta-tag:closed-questions] tags ([like these](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specific-question+closed-questions))), or flag your question as "other (requires moderator attention)" and explain to them why the question shouldn't have been closed.

Comment: Don't forget the even better way: Refer to the (suggested?) duplicate in an edit to the question. If done within a few days, this will autmatically put it into the reopen queue. No need to bother the mods.